# Access data in a file by column in R?

Tags: r, csv

If I have this file:

```
symbol,length,pval
a,5.196415406,0.02376069902
b,4.269985245,0.01861663475
c,3.591334103,0.01391749469
```

I wanna read the file and access it by column, like data$symbol or data$length: 
here is my code:

```
res <- read.csv(file="myfile.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
data <- as.matrix(res)
```

but data$symbol doesn't work,

any help,

Thanks

Comment: `data[, "symbol"]` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You converted your object to a matrix and so will need to extract accordingly.  You can refer to the column names as follows:

```
data[, 'symbol']
data[, 'length']
data[, 'pval']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `as.matrix` is the problem: a matrix cannot access columns via the `obj$col` syntax. Just remove the conversion to access the data.frame columns via `$`.

Or, if you absolutely need the data to be in a matrix, access columns via the subsetting syntax `obj[, 'col']`.